# Saving outputs as record in class & update if same product name given as input python

Tags: python, class

I've a code like this.

```
class salesperson:
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        self.market_price=0
        self.quantity=0
        self.product_name=0
        
        
        #if self.product_name != self.product_name:
            
           
        #self.finalamount=0
        
        
    def buy_pro(self, product_name, market_price, quantity):
        self.product_name = product_name
        self.market_price=market_price
        self.quantity=quantity
        
        self.a= ({self.product_name: [self.market_price, self.quantity]})
    
    def get_value(self):
        
            #self.buyproduct()
            finalamount = self.market_price * -self.quantity
            
        
            return finalamount
      
   
        
    def get_name(self):
        return (self.name)
    
  
    def get_record(self):
        return (self.a)
```

input:

```
sp_name=salesperson('name')
sp_name.buy_pro('mobile',30,20)
sp_name.get_value() 
sp_name.get_record()
```

output:

```
600
Explanation(30*20 =600)
```

Know, If I give same input with same item name, Then record should be updated.

```
    Example:
    sp_name.buy_pro('mobile',10,2)
    sp_name.get_value()
    sp_name.get_record()
```

Expected output:

```
620
Explination(As item name is same (600(previous value) + (10*2)20= 620
```

But output I'm getting.

```
20
```

Can you guys pls suggest what Is the logic I can use that previous value is added to current input if product name is same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use these codes under def **init**():**

```
self.last=""
self.finalamount=0
```

**and use this get_value():**

```
def get_value(self):
    if self.last == self.name:
        self.finalamount += self.market_price * self.quantity
    else:
        self.finalamount = self.market_price * self.quantity
        
    self.last=self.name
    return self.finalamount
```

**or you can create a list of last_names for compare with after names**

**fullcode:**

```
class salesperson:
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        self.market_price=0
        self.quantity=0
        self.product_name=0
        
        self.last=""
        self.finalamount=0        
        
    def buy_pro(self, product_name, market_price, quantity):
        self.product_name = product_name
        self.market_price=market_price
        self.quantity=quantity
        
        self.a= ({self.product_name: [self.market_price, self.quantity]})
    
    def get_value(self):
        if self.last == self.name:
            self.finalamount += self.market_price * self.quantity
        else:
            self.finalamount = self.market_price * self.quantity
            
        self.last=self.name
        return self.finalamount    
        
    def get_name(self):
        return (self.name)

        

sp_name=salesperson('name')

sp_name.buy_pro('mobile',30,20)
print(sp_name.get_value())

sp_name.buy_pro('mobile',10,2)
print(sp_name.get_value())
```

Comment: Hi this was nice explanation..But, Have checked expected outputs?...I mean My expected outputs should be 620...But here when I implement your code I'm getting 820...Here previous record is 600..so new record with same item should (600(old)+(10*2))=620

Comment: Actually, I don't get any error, isn't this the whole code? I've updated it.

Comment: Yes, this is whole code

Comment: ~Thanks man. It's working

Comment: but you want memory for control next names dont forget use last name list :)

Answer (score 1):

in method buy_pro the line which states `self.quantity=quantity` should be `self.quantity += quantity`  This will update the self.quantity value with the current order quatity